# How to access MainPage instance from App on Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I preload webview content then assign to MainPage.Content, it's easy from MainPage class. How can I access MainPage class instance and set Content from **App.xaml.cs**?

**WWW.cs**

```
public static class WWW
{
    public static WebView MyWeb;
    ...
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ...
    public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       Content = WWW.MyWeb;
    }
    ...
 }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
{

   //This line won't refresh the visible webview
   //WWW.MyWeb.Source = uri.ToString();


   //So I try to preload the url then update the Content

   //Preload page html
   string baseUrl = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
   string html = Get(uri.ToString());
   WWW.MyWeb.Source = new Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource() { BaseUrl = baseUrl, Html = html };


   //Now it's time to update MainPage's Content:
   //**Question is: How can I access MainPage instance and it's Content?**


   base.OnAppLinkRequestReceived(uri);

 }
```

**Update:** I think the definition of **MainPage** makes the confusion:

```
public App()
{

     InitializeComponent();
     MainPage = new MainPage();

}
```

Comment: `App` has [`MainPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#mainpage-property) property

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski There is no MainPage.Content btw. I need the instance.

Comment: In the `MainPage = new MainPage();`, the two MainPage are different. One is App.MainPage and another is a contentPage called MainPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration is below:

```
MainPage = new MainPage();
```

Since type of **MainPage** is Page and **new MainPage()** instantiates ContentPage the fix is:

```
((ContentPage)MainPage).Content = WWW.MyWeb;
```